# SetInterval rerun function

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript function:

```
function One(){
    setInterval(function(){ //piece of code },3000);

    setInterval(function(){ //piece of code },3000);

    setInterval(function(){ One(); },3000);
}
```

As you can see,i want the first piece of code to be executed after 3 seconds,then it jumps to the second setInterval and run the code inside after 3 seconds,then it jumps to the third setInterval which re-runs the entire function,but it doesn't work...it runs the first piece of code, and the second one ,and at the third , instead of re running the function,it keeps executing the second piece of code.

Comment: You probably want setTimeout and not setInterval.

Comment: its async issue. Use promises or sync functions from async.js library.
callbacks might be confusing in your code if you are not careful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `setTimeout` instead. `setInterval()` will call it over and over, you only want it to call once each time you call `One()`. Then you can chain them together like so:

```
function One(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        //piece of code A

        setTimeout(function(){ 
            //piece of code B

            setTimeout(function(){ 
                One(); //restart
            },3000);

        },3000);

    },3000);
}
```

Comment: awesome,that's it , just one little issue,the second setTimeout calls the code faster than the first one...

Comment: what do you mean `calls the code faster than the first one`?

Comment: nevermind, i was doing something wrong in my code,thanks a lot

Comment: @PetruLebada sure thing. make sure to mark the question as answered so others seeing this question will know that this answered your question.